# I have a problem with saving selected items

Tags: javascript, html

```
      <div class="box-body">

    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.iduser" id="iduser" />

    <hr />
    <table class="table table-striped grid-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Object</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>
             <button class="btn btn-default" id="selectOrUnselect" onClick="toggleSelect()">Select  
               All</button>
           </tr>
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<dh.Models.getResult>)Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.object</td>
                <td>@item.nameObj</td>
                <td>




                    <div class="pure-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" object="@item.object" class="dhobject"
                checked="@(item.iduser == ViewBag.iduser ? true : false)"                             
                name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
               <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
                    </div>



                  </td>
              </tr>
            }
       </table>

      <input type="hidden" value="@ViewData["iduser"]" name="iduser" id="iduser" class="iduser" />
          </div>
          <div class="box-footer clearfix">
        </div>
      </div>

            @section scripts
             {
              <script type="text/javascript">
               $('#selectOrUnselect').click(function () {
               var iduser = $('.iduser').val();
               var object= $(this).attr('object');
               var dh= $(this).prop('checked'); 
               var dh= $('.dhobject').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
                 $.ajax({
                        url: UrlSettingsDocument.OrgUnits,
                        data: { iduser: iduser, object: object, dh: dh},
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (result) {
                        if (result.result == "Redirect") {
                        window.location = result.url;
                }

            }
        });
    });

// var used to toggle
let allSelected = true
// get the button, use to change the inside text
const btnSelect = document.getElementById("selectOrUnselect")

// get all the checkboxes
const dhobject= document.getElementsByClassName("dhobject")

function toggleSelect() {
    // change check to uncheck or uncheck to check
    for (let i = 0; i < dhobject.length; ++i) {
        dhobject[i].checked = allSelected;
    }
    // change button text 
    if (allSelected) {
        btnSelect.innerText = "Unselect All"
    } else {
        btnSelect.innerText = "Select All"
    }
    allSelected = !allSelected
    }
```

I have a problem with select all button, when i click to select all checkboxes, I successfuly select all of them, but when i click button back, and after i come back to that grid nothing was saved, all boxes are unselected.
What i need to is to after selecting all boxes and when i come back on that grid that should be saved.

Comment: Can you update the question with your router configuration?

Comment: When you come back to page, all the settings will be reset to default. You have to store the state of checkboxes in your app some where globally or in localStorage, so that you can compare and set the checkbox state

Comment: I think something was wrong with my code(js), i can select one by one checkbox and that's alright, but when i sellect all and then back nothing was saved.
So when i fix code that i only can select one by one boxes, it saved successfuly, but when i put sellect all button and try to select them all, nothing is saved.